# Is it possible to enable sitecore Geoip without enabling sitecore Analytics?

Tags: xdb, geo-location

We are using sitecore 9.1 and we are not using sitecore analytics.
Now we want to enable sitecore geoip feature to detect the location of the user and then redirect to the specific local site. But from the sitecore documentation(link below) I understand that sitecore analytics needs to be enabled for geoip feature.

So I wanted to know if there is any way I can use sitecore geoip without enabling sitecore analytics.

https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/90/sitecore-experience-manager/en/set-up-sitecore-ip-geolocation.html#subscribe-to-the-sitecore-ip-geolocation-service

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/91/platform-administration-and-architecture/en/enable-disable-the-xdb-and-the-tracker.html is described what happens if you enable/disabled the xdb and the tracker.

I am not sure what do you mean without Enabling Sitecore Analytics, is it a XM environment ?

If you have the tracking enabled and xdb is disabled  you can use Geo IP on CD servers.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The document itself says you can use the Sitecore Geolocation module without Sitecore analytics. **The Sitecore IP Geolocation module is fully compatible with Sitecore Experience Manager (CMS-only mode).**

The CMS-only mode is basically Sitecore without xDB. CMS-only mode lets you run Sitecore without enabling the Experience Database (xDB) or purchasing xDB licenses. Please review the document again and also you can confirm this on the below link - https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/90/platform-administration-and-architecture/en/cms-only-mode-compatibility.html