# Issue with Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.StartAnalytics.StartTracking processor

Tags: xdb, geo-location

We are using Sitecore 9.1 update 1 in XM only mode.
We wanted to use Sitecore geoIP, so enabled tracking but XDB is still disabled.
([Is it possible to enable sitecore Geoip without enabling sitecore Analytics?](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/28843/is-it-possible-to-enable-sitecore-geoip-without-enabling-sitecore-analytics))

Config below :

```
  <setting name="Analytics.PerformLookup" set:value="true" />
  <setting name="EXM.Enabled" set:value="false" />
  <setting name="DeviceDetection.Enabled" set:value="false" />
  <setting name="Xdb.Enabled" set:value="false" />
  <setting name="Xdb.Tracking.Enabled" set:value="true" />
```

After these changes the geoIP is working fine in CM but there is issue while starting the tracking only in CD(above config is same in both CM and CD). As per the stack trace there is issue in StartTracking processor and it is looking for master db but master db is not required in CD.
Hence confused as to why we are getting this error.

Stack Trace below :

```
3752 10:11:49 ERROR Error in GeoLocationRedirect processor of mvc.requestBegin pipeline -    at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.GetConfigNode(String xpath, Boolean assert)
   at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(String configPath, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)
   at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.GetDatabase(String name, Boolean assert)
   at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.GetDatabase(String name)
   at Sitecore.Marketing.xMgmt.Definitions.Profiles.Data.ItemDb.ProfileDefinitionItemRepository..ctor(ILogger`1 logger, String databaseName, Boolean assumeActive, IDefinitionRecordMapper`1 mapper)
   at Sitecore.Marketing.xMgmt.Definitions.Profiles.Data.ItemDb.ProfileDefinitionItemRepository..ctor(ILogger`1 logger, IItemRepositoriesSettings settings, IDefinitionRecordMapper`1 mapper)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(ScopedCallSite scopedCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(ScopedCallSite scopedCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   at Sitecore.Marketing.Definitions.DefinitionManagerFactory.GetDefinitionManager[TDefinition]()
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Data.MarketingDefinitions.<>c__DisplayClass7_0.<.ctor>b__4()
   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
   at System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue()
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Data.MarketingDefinitions.InitializeProfilesWithDefaultValues()
   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
   at System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue()
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Data.TrackingField.InitializeProfiles()
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Data.TrackingField..ctor(Field innerField, DefinitionManagerFactory factory)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Data.TrackingField.GetTrackingField(Item item)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Data.TrackingField.FindTrackingField(Item item)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.DefaultTracker.IgnoreCurrentItem()
   at Sitecore.Analytics.DefaultTracker.StartTracking()
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.StartAnalytics.StartTracking.Process(PipelineArgs args)
   at (Object , Object )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.XConnect.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounters.OperationPerformanceMonitorExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<Monitor>b__0()
   at Sitecore.Analytics.XConnect.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounters.OperationPerformanceMonitorExtensions.Monitor[T](OperationPerformanceMonitorBase monitor, Func`1 operation)
   at xyz.Custom.Pipelines.GeoLocationRedirect.Process(RequestBeginArgs args)
Exception: System.InvalidOperationException
Message: Could not find configuration node: databases/database[@id='master']
Source: Sitecore.Kernel
   at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.GetConfigNode(String xpath, Boolean assert)
   at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(String configPath, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)
   at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.GetDatabase(String name, Boolean assert)
   at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.GetDatabase(String name)
   at Sitecore.Marketing.xMgmt.Definitions.Profiles.Data.ItemDb.ProfileDefinitionItemRepository..ctor(ILogger`1 logger, String databaseName, Boolean assumeActive, IDefinitionRecordMapper`1 mapper)
   at Sitecore.Marketing.xMgmt.Definitions.Profiles.Data.ItemDb.ProfileDefinitionItemRepository..ctor(ILogger`1 logger, IItemRepositoriesSettings settings, IDefinitionRecordMapper`1 mapper)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(ScopedCallSite scopedCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(ScopedCallSite scopedCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   at Sitecore.Marketing.Definitions.DefinitionManagerFactory.GetDefinitionManager[TDefinition]()
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Data.MarketingDefinitions.<>c__DisplayClass7_0.<.ctor>b__4()
   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
   at System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue()
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Data.MarketingDefinitions.InitializeProfilesWithDefaultValues()
   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
   at System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue()
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Data.TrackingField.InitializeProfiles()
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Data.TrackingField..ctor(Field innerField, DefinitionManagerFactory factory)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Data.TrackingField.GetTrackingField(Item item)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Data.TrackingField.FindTrackingField(Item item)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.DefaultTracker.IgnoreCurrentItem()
   at Sitecore.Analytics.DefaultTracker.StartTracking()
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.StartAnalytics.StartTracking.Process(PipelineArgs args)
   at (Object , Object )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.XConnect.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounters.OperationPerformanceMonitorExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<Monitor>b__0()
   at Sitecore.Analytics.XConnect.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounters.OperationPerformanceMonitorExtensions.Monitor[T](OperationPerformanceMonitorBase monitor, Func`1 operation)
   at xyz.Custom.Pipelines.GeoLocationRedirect.Process(RequestBeginArgs args)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the stack trace it indicates that it cannot find a certain configuration/setting. You might be missing a file in CD server.
Check that your CD server that it has all the relevant *.config files enabled and disabled, especially those files that has Marketing name on it.

Comment: Yes, some files related to marketing were disabled in CD server. After enabling the files it started working fine. Below are the files which were disabled Sitecore.MarketingCD.config Sitecore.Marketing.Lucene.Index.Web.config
Sitecore.Marketing.Lucene.IndexConfiguration.config